# ln: failed to create hard link | No such file or directory - Even when file exists

Tags: samba, symbolic-link, hardlink, ln

Running Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS using a Samba share (Version 4.17.12-Debian) running on Proxmox.

The command: `ln "/mnt/drive/downloads/movie.mkv" "/mnt/drive/movies/movie/movie.mkv"`

The error: `ln: failed to create hard link '/mnt/drive/downloads/movie.mkv' => '/mnt/drive/movies/movie/movie.mkv': No such file or directory`

What works:

- Creating hard link in Proxmox
- Creating symlink in Ubuntu
- Renaming the file and then hard linking it
- Renaming the file and making a new one in its place then hard linking it

I also tried restarting Samba, it didn't fix it. Restarting the Ubuntu client does fix it, but I'd like a solution that doesn't involve restarting.

If anyone has any idea what causes this and/or how to fix it with minimal interruption, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Check this Q/A, maybe it can help: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/137192/101265